# If I'm asked to prove $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$, can I assume the euclidean metric?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Using the definition of limit if I'm asked to prove $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $0$, can I assume the euclidean metric?

Comment: When working in $\mathbb{R}$, unless explicitly specified otherwise, you can assume the usual metric.

Answer (score 2):

For organization, I'll turn [Daniel's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057757/if-im-asked-to-prove-1-n-from-n-1-to-infiniti-converges-to-0-can-i-assume-th#comment2153163_1057757) into an answer:

> When working in $\Bbb R$, unless explicitly specified otherwise, you can assume the usual metric.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is meant to be a supplemental explanation. It is fairly easy to prove that the sequence converges if we are working with Euclidean metric. On the other hand, if we are working with other type of metric, the sequence may not be convergent at all! An example would be the metric defined as:

> $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$.

In this metric, consider the expression $d(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{m})$, it will always be $1$.